# Pass parameters from twig to angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, twig

I'm new to Angular and Symfony and I'm asking if variables that I give to the view with twig can be used by an angular controller?

Here is an example :

PHP Controller:

```
return $this->render('view.html', array('variable' => $value));
```

Angular Controller:

```
var data = 'variablefromtwig';
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

symfony controller:

```
return $this->render('view.html', array('twigvar' => $value));
```

twigtemplate:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.value('twigVar', '{{twigvar}}');    
app.controller('myController', function(twigVar){    
  alert(twigVar);
}); 
</script>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value

Answer (score 0):

You can print this variable in JS value assignment statement.

In your twig template, set JS variable. It should be visible in angular controllers:

```
<script>
var data = '{{variable}}';
</script>
```

But in my opinion best solution is to read all required data through async ajax request just in angular controllers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking about ajax in agularjs controller. I will continue with this solution.